# Disabling editing on a specific system ui-dialog - android

Tags: java, android

There is a specific dialog in the systemUI that I would not like the user to make editing or input text. Is there a way to do this? For example, I want to disable the editing of the number of copies in the print dialog. Can I do it either disabling the keyboard or disabling the input into the field?

Comment: editText.setEnabled(false); will help you.

Comment: systemUI is a system app. do you have the right to change the systemUI source, make a new ROM and push to users?

Comment: well I would love to created or change an systemUI but what I want is just either to hide the keyboard or intercept a field in the dialog box to prevent input. For example, I would like to disable the number of copies field in the print dialog box. How do I do that?